Unable to handle native popup on iOS/Chromium in Selenium tests
I'm running Selenium WebDriver tests on iOS using Chromium in BrowserStack, and I keep encountering a native popup when I submit a form that says:

"The information you're about to submit is not secure. Because this form is being submitted using a connection that's not secure, your information will be visible to others."

The popup has two options:

"Cancel"
"Send Anyway"

Refer the screenshot below -

Note - I am using a staging Ip.
I’ve tried several approaches to handle this alert, but nothing seems to be working. Here's what I've tried so far:

Switching to the alert using driver.switchTo().alert().accept(). However, this doesn’t detect the popup as an alert.

Using JavaScriptExecutor to override the window.confirm function:
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");


Adding various ChromeOptions such as:
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");


Adding BrowserStack-specific capabilities like autoAcceptAlerts:
caps.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);




you'd need to use a robot-like framework for automating that prompt.  (something running at OS level...)  Or just self-sign staging server and add trust for the cert.

We would need to handle such native warning pop up through automation code manually, this cannot be handled through capabilities, we can try to use appium inspector to inspect the elements to perform the clicks

Yes, but unfortunately I don't have browserstack premium and I am using Windows so I can't use Appium inspector.
